# IP Adress, Proxy и WiFi

Tags: ip, proxy, wifi

На работе корпоративная сеть. Используется proxy. При открытии браузера требует авторизации. При запуске браузера с NO PROXY есть доступ к некоторым сайтам. Но один комп открыт ко всем сайтам, даже запрещенным, через proxy. Я переставляю сетевые провода, но ничего не меняется, даже динамический IP. Почему? Изначально я хочу через WiFi USB адаптер раздать интернет с этого компа. Инет на WiFi появляется только после объединений в мост, но пропадает на компе. Поставить галочку и расшарить не получается, ругается на невозможность с (null) и какую-то смену IP-адресов. Как раздать интернет по WiFi или, может, через хаб подключить еще один компьютер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

программа Connectify решила проблему. Не был установлен framework 4.5 и эта прога создает специальную службу для работы wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше купить аппаратный Wi-Fi маршрутизатор и использовать его. По соотношению цена/качество - это лучшее решение.

Comment: адаптр купленный в китае за 30р работает вроде, но он предназначен на прием,хотя и на на раздачу исправно работает, только не там.